# Warning: Unknown event handler property `onCellEditStarted`

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, fetch, apollo

I have this error when i have implemented the api fetching
via apollo , query

```
class Vehicles extends Component {
  state = {
    columns : [
      { title: 'VIN', field: "VIN"},
      { title: 'REGISTRATION_PLATE', field: 'REGISTRATION_PLATE' },
      // { title: 'Contract', initialEditValue :'customer' , field: 'contract' , lookup: {'customer' : 'Customer 1'} },
      // { title: 'Debit', initialEditValue : 100, field: 'debit'  , type : 'numeric' ,},
      // { title: 'Credit', initialEditValue : 100, field: 'credit', type : 'numeric', }

    ],
    data : [

    ],
    active: "1"
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(vehicleQuery)
    this.props.client.query({
        query: vehicleQuery,
      }
    ).then(values =>{
      var mapped = _.map(values.data.vehicleQuery, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['VIN','REGISTRATION_PLATE']));
      console.log(mapped)
      this.setState({data : mapped})
    })
  }

  toggle = tab => {
    if (this.state.active !== tab) {
      this.setState({ active: tab })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Breadcrumbs
          breadCrumbTitle="Vehicles"
          breadCrumbParent="Working Area"
          breadCrumbActive="Vehicles"
        />
        <div>
          <Button.Ripple className="mr-1 mb-1 bg-gradient-primary" color="none" onClick={() =>this.props.history.push('/car/add')}>Add New Vehicle</Button.Ripple>
        </div>
        <Nav tabs className="nav-justified">
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              className={classnames({
                active: this.state.active === "1"
              })}
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggle("1")
              }}
            >
              All
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              className={classnames({
                active: this.state.active === "2"
              })}
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggle("2")
              }}
            >
              Active
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink
              className={classnames({
                active: this.state.active === "3"
              })}
              onClick={() => {
                this.toggle("3")
              }}
            >
              Borrowed
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <TabContent activeTab={this.state.active}>
          <TabPane tabId="1">
            <Table title={'All Vehicles'} data={this.state} onRowAdd={this.onRowAdd} onRowUpdate={this.onRowUpdate} onRowDelete={this.onRowDelete}/>
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane tabId="2">
            <Table title={'Active Vehicles'} data={this.state} onRowAdd={this.onRowAdd} onRowUpdate={this.onRowUpdate} onRowDelete={this.onRowDelete}/>

          </TabPane>
          <TabPane tabId="3">
            <Table title={'Borrowed Vehicles'} data={this.state} onRowAdd={this.onRowAdd} onRowUpdate={this.onRowUpdate} onRowDelete={this.onRowDelete}/>

          </TabPane>
        </TabContent>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(withApollo(Vehicles));
```

when running i got this error

```
index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `cellEditable` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `celleditable` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
    in td (created by ForwardRef(TableCell))
    in ForwardRef(TableCell) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)) (created by MTableCell)
    in MTableCell (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
    in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in MTableBodyRow (created by MTableBody)
    in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
    in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
    in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
    in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
    in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
    in Container (created by MaterialTable)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
    in MaterialTable
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (at table.js:43)
    in div (at table.js:42)
    in Table (at vehicles.js:97)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in TabPane (at vehicles.js:96)
    in div (created by TabContent)
    in TabContent (at vehicles.js:95)
    in Vehicles (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ApolloConsumer (created by withApollo(Vehicles))
    in withApollo(Vehicles) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:113)
    in Suspense (at Router.js:112)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:277)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:271)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:255)
    in VerticalLayout (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:111)
    in Route (at Router.js:98)
    in RouteConfig (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:189)
    in Switch (at Router.js:144)
    in Router (at Router.js:143)
    in ApolloProvider (at Router.js:142)
    in AppRouter (at App.js:11)
    in App (at src/index.js:29)
    in Layout (at src/index.js:28)
    in Suspense (at src/index.js:27)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:26)

index.js:1 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onCellEditStarted`. It will be ignored.
    in td (created by ForwardRef(TableCell))
    in ForwardRef(TableCell) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)) (created by MTableCell)
    in MTableCell (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
    in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in MTableBodyRow (created by MTableBody)
    in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
    in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
    in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
    in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
    in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
    in Container (created by MaterialTable)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
    in MaterialTable
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (at table.js:43)
    in div (at table.js:42)
    in Table (at vehicles.js:97)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in TabPane (at vehicles.js:96)
    in div (created by TabContent)
    in TabContent (at vehicles.js:95)
    in Vehicles (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ApolloConsumer (created by withApollo(Vehicles))
    in withApollo(Vehicles) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:113)
    in Suspense (at Router.js:112)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:277)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:271)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:255)
    in VerticalLayout (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:111)
    in Route (at Router.js:98)
    in RouteConfig (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:189)
    in Switch (at Router.js:144)
    in Router (at Router.js:143)
    in ApolloProvider (at Router.js:142)
    in AppRouter (at App.js:11)
    in App (at src/index.js:29)
    in Layout (at src/index.js:28)
    in Suspense (at src/index.js:27)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:26)
index.js:1 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onCellEditFinished`. It will be ignored.
    in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
    in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in MTableBodyRow (created by MTableBody)
    in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
    in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
    in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
    in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
    in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
    in Container (created by MaterialTable)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
    in MaterialTable
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (at table.js:43)
    in div (at table.js:42)
    in Table (at vehicles.js:97)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in TabPane (at vehicles.js:96)
    in div (created by TabContent)
    in TabContent (at vehicles.js:95)
    in Vehicles (created by Context.Consumer)
    in ApolloConsumer (created by withApollo(Vehicles))
    in withApollo(Vehicles) (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:113)
    in Suspense (at Router.js:112)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:277)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:271)
    in div (at VerticalLayout.js:255)
    in VerticalLayout (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:111)
    in Route (at Router.js:98)
    in RouteConfig (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at Router.js:189)
    in Switch (at Router.js:144)
    in Router (at Router.js:143)
    in ApolloProvider (at Router.js:142)
    in AppRouter (at App.js:11)
    in App (at src/index.js:29)
    in Layout (at src/index.js:28)
    in Suspense (at src/index.js:27)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:26)
```

Table.js

```
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MaterialTable
          icons={tableIcons}
          title={this.props.title}
          columns={this.props.data.columns}
          data={this.props.data.data}
          editable={{
            onRowAdd : this.props.onRowAdd && ((newData) => this.props.onRowAdd(newData)),
            onRowUpdate:this.props.onRowAdd && ((newData,oldData) =>this.props.onRowUpdate(newData,oldData)),
            onRowDelete: this.props.onRowAdd && ((oldData) =>this.props.onRowDelete(oldData)),
          }}
          options={{
            filtering: true
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

i have followed the documentation in the material table ui
and tried to fetch data with promises like this

```
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

<MaterialTable
    // other props
    data={query =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // prepare your data and then call resolve like this:
            resolve({
                data: // your data array
                page: // current page number
                totalCount: // total row number
            });
        })
    }
/>;
```

But when passing the apollo query function i get this error :

```
cannot read then of type undefined
```

what i need to achieve is to set an array of data to make the material table read from it